# How did 'knight' semantically specialise to mean acquirer of a target company?

Tags: etymology, business-language

From my research on chess, I know that the knight jumps [to the opposite corner of a 2x3 rectangle](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/23876), and is the only piece that can jump over all other pieces.
[image]

[But measured in points, the knight isn't the strongest piece.](https://www.quora.com/How-many-points-is-each-chess-piece-worth)  [image]

What semantic notions underlie 'knight' and its company takeover connotation? [White Knight](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/w/whiteknight.asp)

> A white knight is a hostile takeover defense whereby a 'friendly' individual or company that acquires a corporation at fair consideration that is on the verge of being taken over by an 'unfriendly' bidder or acquirer, who is known as the black knight. Although the target company does not remain independent, acquisition by a white knight is still preferred to the hostile takeover.

> #### FAST FACT

> The terms white knight and black knight can find their origin the adversarial game of chess.

Comment: Why do you assume that it has something to do with chess?  "White knight" and "black knight" are in fact old terms for a good knight and an evil one.

Comment: Knights rescue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s based on an incorrect assumption.

Comment: @Mary Because Investopedia proclaims "The terms white knight and black knight can find their origin the adversarial game of chess"? Do you see this in my post?

Comment: @Xanne Isn't it more educative to correct any "incorrect assumption", rather than closing my question?

Comment: I agree that white and black most likely refer to the symbolic opposite meaning they represent  (doves and hawks, good and evil, peace and war). And a knight also refers to  a historical figure of a conqueror. So the question is: When (possibly why) did white and black knights became associated with friendly or hostile business transactions? The question is an interesting one.

Comment: The "Fast Fact" in the article suggests that the origin _could_ lie in chess but the body of the text then goes on to say that there is the related concept of a "white squire" defence where a friendly investor takes a stake in the company rather than taking it over. Since squires existed in medieval times (they were assistants to knights who were on the way to being a knights themselves) but do not exist in chess this rather weakens the idea that the term comes from chess.

Comment: I will also vote to close the question as it incorporates the non-sequitur of a chess lesson and the modern use of corporate takeovers. I cannot help but think the Fast Fact is wrong; The history of knights goes back to before the European introduction of chess and its familiar pieces.

Comment: https://youtu.be/mA73dTr9CSs

Comment: If it weren't for the bounty, I would vote to close the question as off-topic. It might be better suited to chess SE (after removing the reference to corporate mergers and acquisition from Investopedia, which makes the chess part seem like an anachronism). I t really isn't clear what you are asking, and why you're asking on EL&U, no offense intended.

Comment: It is unlikely that the terms have anything to do with chess, because white and black knights are bound to be doing very different things in their attempts at a corporate takeover, while white and black knights in chess perform exactly the **same** functions for their respective sides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There could be a case made for it, but I don't think it comes from or has any direct relation to chess. In the context of business mergers and acquisitions (M&A), there are four types of "knights." These colored knights are used to represent the various roles of participants in an actual or potential company takeover.

> A black knight is a company that makes an unwelcome takeover offer
> for a target company. This hostile takeover may proceed via a tender
> offer, a proxy fight, or by purchasing shares on the open
> market.[[1]](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/blackknight.asp)

A white knight refers to a type of defense against a black knight bidder. While the target company still loses its independence, the white knight investor is more favorable to shareholders and management.

> A white knight investor describes a friendly company arriving at the
> messy scene of a hostile takeover and acquiring the target company.
> The white knight may slay the hostile bidder with a higher bid or a
> more favourable deal for the target board's management.[[2]](https://corporatelawuk.typepad.com/corporate_blawg/2006/09/white_knight.html)

In addition to the white knight and black knight, there may be a third corporate entity, called a gray knight. This unsolicited bidder enters the scene in order to take advantage of problems between the first bidder (the black knight) and the target company, possibly even trying to takeover the black knight (predator) company.[[3]](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/%7Eigiddy/articles/merger_glossary.htm) Although friendlier than a black knight, the gray knight still seeks to serve its own interests, and is not as desirable as a white knight.

A yellow knight is a company that was planning a hostile takeover attempt, but backs down into a merger with the target company, following an aggressive acquisition attempt.[[4]](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/y/yellowknight.asp) (If present in the transaction, the yellow knight is usually the same company that was initially the black knight.)

Clearly the word "knight" has kept its original connotations, as it symbolizes power, valiance, and sometimes benevolence. I think that the colors of the knights are what sparked the application of the general word "knight" to business lingo.

From dictionary.com, "The notion of a **white knight** dates back to at least the 12th century, when French poet Chrétien de Troyes referred to the legendary Lancelot as the Blanc Chevalier (“White Knight” in French) in his Arthurian writings."

**White** symbolizes purity and health in most cultures - this is why you will commonly see rescuers in movies on white horses. A white knight acquisition is when a company will "rescue" a financially struggling entity through acquisition.

**Yellow** symbolizes many good things, but also cowardice. A yellow knight takeover is when a company is initially aggressive/hostile in their takeover attempt, but mellows out and proposes a merger eventually.

**Gray** symbolizes shade, dullness, and concealment. A gray knight comes out of the shadows as a second corporate bidder in an acquisition.

Finally, **Black** symbolizes ill intent and darkness when it comes to acquisitions, which is why black knight acquisitions are predatory in nature.

Overall, the term "knight" keeps its same meaning and connotations, but when put together with colors, it changes the "intentions" of the knight. It doesn't have to do with chess or a semantic change of the word itself.

Comment: It should be noted, though, that *white knight* is the only one among these expressions that is widely used outside the context of corporate takeovers. Chances are that *white knight* is the first among these expressions to be used within that context, which was an application of its general meaning. It is probably after that usage of *white knight* became established in the world of business, that people invented the other terms listed here.

Answer (score 7):

This has nothing to do with chess!  The *Shorter OED* app on my computer has ***white** (adjective) figurative,* *"**Free from malignity or evil intent; beneficent**, harmless. Chiefly in special collocations below,"* one of those being *white knight*.  It also says to compare with the senses of *black* as in foul, wicked, hateful, sinister, etc.

So, the white knight defends against sinister agression, such as a *hostile* takeover?  Makes sense to me!